# Turn off translations for react-admin

Tags: react-admin

Developing an admin that has no need for translations.  Is there a way to turn them off completely.   As it is now, for things like doing notifications, they display but I also get a console warning about missing key for translation.

Comment: Which translation warnings are you seeing? It must be on your custom components, because react-admin components don't throw translation warnings in case of missing translation for a field label. It uses the (non-documented- default translation everywhere

Comment: See https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/758

Comment: It may also be because some of our call to translate do not use this feature so if you can find those, open an issue :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Frederik's answer, here's the right way to disable the 'missing translations' warnings on react-admin:

```
import polyglotI18nProvider from 'ra-i18n-polyglot'; // install the package
import englishMessages from 'ra-language-english'; // install the package

const App = () => {

  const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(() => englishMessages, 'en', { allowMissing: true });

  return (

     <Admin i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
       ...
     />

  )

}
```

Comment: Not really. You are assuming that it's a single language application since you throw away the locale in the polyglotI18nProvider function and you're also assuming the provided translations are just the translations in the React Admin dependency. This will only work for single language apps that only use the RA translations and use translated strings as keys in the codebase.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding a custom i18nProvider that allows missing keys:

```
const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(locale => i18nMessages[locale], 'en', { allowMissing: true });

<Admin
    i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
    ...
/>
```

More details: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html
and: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyglot#options-overview

Comment: How can I import 'i18nMessages'?

Comment: @YukiTanaka i18nMessages is a dict of all the translations. You can import the english messages form `ra-language-english`. You can check the docs here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html